# unable to get numeric answers getting symbolic

Tags: equation-solving

The assumptions don't get used and mathematica lacks 3-D vector functions?
How can I get the results that I want in a numeric form?
I want to find the angle between a and b it should be near 90 degrees.
The other question was about how to get an angle now the question is purely about why I can not get a numeric result and the answers appear in symbols

```
$Assumptions = {a, e, b} \[Element] Vectors[3, Reals] && 
 a.a == b.b == 156 && e.e == 1 &&
 a.e == b.e == 90 &&
 p == a - (a.e) e &&
 q == b - (b.e) e
 Simplify[Dot[a, b]
 dotAB = (p + (a.e) e).(q + (b.e) e)
 Simplify[TensorExpand[%]]
(*want p.q +(a.e)(b.e) since*)
(*a.e)e.q =p.e (a.e)\[Equal]0*)
(*a.b should be equal to -18.*)
```

I am editing this as comments have be expressed that the question is unclear or incomplete. I wish to solve a problem that arises from chemistry. Certain molecule has a configuration of a regular hexagon (sides the same length and angles the same.) The conformation however is "boat shaped" and  the hexagon is not in the same plane. It is not flat. I have the length of side 156 units with the vertical distance between planes of 90 units. I chose Mathematica to come up with a numeric answer to the question of what is the angle between any two sides? I can solve this on paper using vectors in 3-D. My attempt is shown.

Comment: How many times do you intend to re-ask nearly the same question?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the actual problem lies in the mathematics, not in Mathematica.

Comment: `a == b` is a possible solution by symmetry, unless `a.b == -18` is meant to be a condition and not a result.  You seem to seek a solution, but it's unclear what the system of equations is.

Comment: This will find a configuration with `a.b` close to `-18`: ``conds = e.e == 1 && a.e == 90 && b.e == 90 && a.a == 156^2 && 
   156^2 == b.b;
Block[{a, b, c, d, e, p, q},
 a = Array[aa, 3];
 b = Array[bb, 3];
 e = Array[ee, 3];
 (*p=a-(a.e) e;
 q=b-Dot[b,e] e;*)
 {min, config} = 
  FindMinimum[{(a.b + 18)^2, conds},
   Evaluate@
    Transpose@{Join[a, b, e], {75.8, 96.4, 96.4, 96.4, 75.8, 
       96.4, -0.43, 0.64, 0.64}}]
 ]``

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer but an extended comment.

Instead of `{a, e, b} \[Element] Vectors[3, Reals]` you should use `a | e | b \[Element] Vectors[3, Reals]`. Otherwise, `a`, `e`, and `b` are implicitly assumed to by real numbers.

It seems that you want

```
Simplify[Dot[a, b]]
```

to return

```
p.q +(a.e)(b.e)
```

There is no way `Simplify` can do that with its default `ComplexityFunction` since `p.q +(a.e)(b.e)` has much higher `LeafCount`:

```
LeafCount[a.b]
LeafCount[p.q + (a.e) (b.e)]
```

> 3
>
> 11

You require Mathematica to do nothing less than reading your mind. You might be better off by formulating a system of equations and using `NSolve`.

Moreover, `a.b.` is not uniquely specified by your given conditions, so don't expect Mathematica to find the one solution that you have in your mind.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the equations given do not imply a numeric value for `a.b`. I show this below, using slightly modified notation.

```
aa = Array[a, 3];
bb = Array[b, 3];
ee = Array[e, 3];
pp = Array[p, 3];
qq = Array[q, 3];
polys = Flatten[{aa.aa - 156, bb.bb - 156, ee.ee - 1, 
    aa - (aa.ee)*ee - pp, bb - (bb.ee)*ee - qq}];
vars = Flatten[{pp, qq, aa, bb, ee}];
```

Compute a Groebner basis for this set of polynomials. With that we can get canonical reductions of various expressions of interest.

```
gb = GroebnerBasis[polys, vars, 
    MonomialOrder -> DegreeReverseLexicographic];
```

Now use it. First check that one stated equality holds.

```
dotAB = (pp + (aa.ee)*ee).(qq + (bb.ee)*ee);
red = PolynomialReduce[dotAB - (pp.qq + (aa.ee)*(bb.ee)), gb, vars, 
   MonomialOrder -> DegreeReverseLexicographic];
red[[2]]

(* Out[487]= 0 *)
```

What is the canonical (with respect to the given term order) form of `dotAB`?

```
PolynomialReduce[dotAB, gb, vars, 
  MonomialOrder -> DegreeReverseLexicographic][[2]]

(* Out[488]= a[1] b[1] + a[2] b[2] + a[3] b[3] *)
```

It actually is equal to `aa.bb`. Good so far. But...it does not have a numeroic value. If one were forced by the equations, it would have appeared in the canonical form.

I will remark that I also voted to close, on grounds that there was not a clear question. But it might be just a mistake in the math somewhere, in expecting a numeric result (if that's what this was about-- again, it was all a bit murky).

Comment: This is not an exact duplicate as some say because in the item submitted as evidence the question was about the technique and this question is not about how so much about why I can not get a number out. Please see my edit above (at the top) that lessens the murkiness of the question. I would rather avoid resorting to lists in the solution.

Comment: (1) As noted, my close vote was based on this being not clear rather than a claim of a duplicate. (2) When I add the equations `aa.ee - 90, bb.ee - 90` I still do not get numeric results. (3) I suspect these are not correct equations for cyclohexane, (4) The method I showed, using explicit equations and a Groebner basis, is one common approach to smallish molecule conformation problems in computational chemistry.